# module arguments override function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, apply

I am refering to my generator method from `module.exports` but its getting `arguments` array of `module` not the called function.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const inc = Promise.coroutine(function* (model, condition, fields, options = {}) {});

module.exports = {
    inc: (model, condition, fields, options = {}) => { 
        //reveiving all the arguments fine
        return inc.apply(null, arguments);  //but "arguments" array contains the values of "module", not the function
    }
};
```

`arguments` array:

```
0 - require function
1 - Module
2 - file path
3 - directory path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrow functions do not bind an arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments).

It should be:

```
module.exports = {
    inc: (...args) => inc(...args)
};
```

Unless exporting it directly causes problems with function context, it can be just:

```
module.exports = {
    inc
};
```

Comment: I got it working, but I didn't understand the issue. Can you explain your first line **Arrow functions do not bind an arguments object**?

Comment: `arguments` cannot be used in arrows to refer to their arguments, and `arguments` refer to parent function scope arguments (module function in your case) - similarly to `this` in arrows. The reference that was linked explains that.

Comment: I understand that `arguments` belong to parent function scope *(which is also explained in the link)* but I don't understand that arrow functions don't/can't have `arguments`. What if arrow function is the parent? I just checked making arrow function parent and received the `arguments` object..

Comment: Then there won't be `arguments` at all. Because arrows don't have their own `arguments` and `this` by design. `arguments` refers to to the one that was received from non-arrow function (module function). If there is no such function, i.e. when a script is evaluated as <script> in browser, `arguments` will be undefined.

Comment: Yes you're right. I was testing it in nodejs, and it behaves differently. Testing in browser proves what you were saying.